# Smooth scroll not working with react-router-hash-link

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router, anchor

I updated react-router to v6 and now when I add smooth to the HashLink it doesn't even scroll.

```json
    "react-router": "^6.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-router-hash-link": "^2.4.3",
```

So I tried to change for a simple `a href` and add `scroll-behavior:smooth` in css but it doesn't work either.

```html
           <div className="navbar__center">
                <nav>
                    <HashLink smooth to="/#home">
                        Home
                    </HashLink>
                    <HashLink smooth to="/#about">
                        About
                    </HashLink>
                    <HashLink smooth to="/#works">
                        Works
                    </HashLink>
                </nav>
            </div>
```

So ofc in the same page I have this:

```html
<section className="home__section home__2" id="about">
```

I can see the hash anchor tag in the url and it will navigate to it if a open it in a new tab but that's all.

The routes:

```js
     <BrowserRouter>
        <main className="main">
          <Routes>

            <Route path="/" element={<Home />}>
            </Route>

            <Route path="*" element = {<FourOhFour/>} />
          
          </Routes>
        </main>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I was just looking into `react-router-hash-link` compatibility with `react-router-dom` v6 yesterday actually. Currently `react-router-hash-link` doesn't work with RRDv6, but there's an open issue [here](https://github.com/rafgraph/react-router-hash-link/issues/92) with a fork that has been updated to support RRDv6. If you are using hash links then I think you should hold off on upgrading to RRDv6, or wait for the hash links repo to be updated.

Comment: how come v6 doesn't support that ?

Comment: @sshmaxime v6 wont support that, see here https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7780